# Replace space indentations into tabs with regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm writing a function that *format* a code snippet that replaces the space indentations into tab indentations.

But the code sometimes uses 2 spaces and sometimes uses 4 spaces as an indentation. I need to conditionally convert them into tabs(Tried to search but didn't find useful infomation).

I'm using javascript in chrome so it allows me to use non-fixed width lookbehinds.

### Input

```js
function foo() {
    if (test) {
        if(test) {
            test;
        } else if(test) {
            test;
            if(test) {
                test;
            }
        }
    }
}

function foo() {
  if (test) {
    if(test) {
      test;
    } else if(test) {
      test;
      if(test) {
        test;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### Output

```js
function foo() {
    if (test) {
        if(test) {
            test;
        } else if(test) {
            test;
            if(test) {
                test;
            }
        }
    }
}

function foo() {
    if (test) {
        if(test) {
            test;
        } else if(test) {
            test;
            if(test) {
                test;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried this regex

```
(?:  (?<=^  (?=\S)[\s\S]*)|    )
```

It works for [this situation](https://regex101.com/r/trfiF1/1/), but not for [this one](https://regex101.com/r/isuXtI/1/). What did I miss?

Comment: What makes 4 spaces one tabstop and not two?

Comment: @Andreas It's kind of random since it's submitted by users. Some of the code snippets uses 2 and some are 4, and some are already tabs that I don't need to touch. But for one code snippet enclosure(that a code snippet starts directly from a newline and ends with a new line with no spaces in between) the spaces are consistent.

Comment: If all the indents in a closure are only divisible by 4, that's considered as 4 spaces indentation, otherwise 2.

Comment: But If there are 2 spaces, it is divisible by 2 which will give 1 tab. If there are 4 spaces it is divisible by 4 and will give 1 tab. https://regex101.com/r/dD2VWr/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird What I was thinking is to detect if there's 2 spaces followed by a non-space character, then it's 2 space indentation. If not, it's 4 space.

Comment: What if space (ascii 32) characters are part of a string? (So not used to indent code but part of the code instead.) I think you should use a tool such as `esprima` to deconstruct the code so you can regenerate it.

Answer (score 0):

What if you grab all spaces with min length 2 and replaces them conditionally like below

```js
let string = `
function foo() {
    if (test) {
        if(test) {
            test;
        } else if(test) {
            test;
            if(test) {
                test;
            }
        }
    }
}
`;

const match = string.match(/^( {2,})/m) || [''];

const is4SpacesTab = match[0].length % 4 === 0 ;

const result = string.replace(/( {2,})/g, (m, g) => Array(is4SpacesTab ? g.length / 4 : g.length / 2).fill('\t').join(''));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: This does not work for 2-space indentation: https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-hermann-g50gr?file=/src/index.js

Comment: @HaoWu, identifying the number of spaces for single tab ahead of string replacement may help. This may not be the best but we could give a try, updated snippet.